# Typo in this proof about harmonic functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, harmonic-functions, curvature

In the proof of Lemma 1.1 of [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.3846.pdf), we read

> The zeros of $f''(x+iy) = 0$ are critical points of $f(x+iy)$.

This claim is essential to the proof yet appears to be wrong.  For example, $f(z) = z^3 + z + 1$ is holomorphic with $f''(z) = 0$ at $z = 0$, yet $f'(z) = 1$.

What (if anything) have I got wrong?  If I do have something wrong, can the proof be salvaged?

Comment: Your $f$ is not harmonic. Try expanding $f$ in a Taylor series about the critical point and use the fact that $f_{xx} + f_{yy} = 0.$

Comment: @Matematleta $f$ is holomorphic hence harmonic though.

Comment: Sorry correct, I did not read your example carefully. . I think the claim should be that if $f$ has a local extremum at $z_0$  and is harmonic then $f''(z_0)=0.$ Now apply my comment,

Comment: The article refers to harmonic functions $\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ and the result is that if $f$ and has a strict local extremum at $(x_0,y_0)$ then all second partial derivatives of $f$ at $(x_0,y_0)$ are $0.$

Comment: @Matematleta I should have been clearer.  The function $f$ is holomorphic, and thus its real part is harmonic.